# Stack Exchange / Overflow blog messages don't onebox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, blog, onebox

There was a [new blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) on the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow blog today, but the Blog bot's message didn't onebox anymore:

[image]

In fact, `blog.stackoverflow.com` links don't seem to onebox at all, whereas others do (e.g. from the Super User community blog).